# Part of query results missing

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to figure out why not all of my query seems to be there when I look at logs that loop through the query results.  I didn't get an error from the query execution.  I know that out of about 16000, I don't see about 2800 of the lines from the query (grep log for a few of the items I was expecting).  This is what it looks like:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('host.net', 'u', 'pw', "DB_Name");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Items
                          FROM TableData
                          WHERE 
                          Items IS NOT NULL
                          LIMIT 40000");

$stmt->bind_result($item);
if(!$stmt->execute()){ //get location id    
   $tempErr = "Location select Error: " . $stmt->error;
   printf($tempErr . "\n"); //show mysql execute error if exists  
}

while($stmt->fetch()) {
  print "item:" . " " . $item;
  print "\n";
}
```

I'm not sure what to search for online to find this answer.  I'm relatively new to php and mysql.

When I run the query, and put an if statement

```
while($stmt->fetch()) {
  if(($item == "11") || ($item == "22") || ($item == "33") ) {
...
```

within the while/fetch, I do see that my DB is updated with those 3.  Why isn't it working for all 16000?

Comment: The php script may have timed out. Try increasing the execution time.

Comment: Where/how do I do that?

Comment: Google: php increase execution time. Or just search here on SO...

Comment: As an aside, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Try running same query in mysql CLI client to check that expected number of records is returned. If it's ok, than it's likely to be php side issue (timeout, etc). Also look at query execution time.

Comment: I did this:  php -i | grep max_execution_time
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
And that means there's no max execution time being hit (it can run forever).

Comment: A friend of mine suggested Innodb locking DB type is something to look into but it's a little over my head.  I was thinking I might have clashes with other scripts running and using the DB.